# Unity Mouse Input without Ray/Raycast and Colliders

Tags: unity-game-engine, input, controls, mouse

First of all thank you for your time. I'm quite new in this so I'm struggling a bit. I'm trying to make a drag and release shooter which doesn't really depend on colliders or raycasts but solely depends on mouse delta and camera position. The way I'm trying to have it done is I'm mapping mouse position (x,y) to velocity direction such as new Vector3(mouseX, 0f, mouseY) then rotating it about Y axis to match the visual drag on the screen.

```
    void OnMouseUp()
{
    releasePos = Input.mousePosition;
    Vector2 m_direction = releasePos - initialPos;
    Vector3 direction = new Vector3(m_direction.x, 0, m_direction.y);
    float userDrag = Mathf.Clamp(direction.magnitude, 0f, maxVelocity);
    direction = Translation(direction);
    direction = Vector3.Normalize(direction);
    rigidbody.velocity = (direction * userDrag) * force;
}

private Vector3 Translation(Vector3 direction)
{
    Vector3 camPos = Camera.main.transform.position;
    camPos.y = 0;
    float angle = Vector3.Angle(new Vector3(0f, 0f, 1f), camPos);
    Quaternion translatedAngle = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.up);
    direction = translatedAngle * direction;
```

But as the angle changes it kinda fails to deliver what I'm asking for. Is there a way I can avoid bunch of if, else statements for the angle value or a shorter way of doing this?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDWGP.png)

Comment: are you trying to shoot bullets to the mouse location or from

Comment: adn unity flips the y, so you will need `Screen.height-mouseposition.y` instead of `mouseposition.y`

Comment: @PrinceOfRavens since I'm getting the delta it works out fine the way it is I think. And I'm trying to drag/release as if it was a "slingshot".

Comment: ahhh ok that sounds about right... so your launching from the mouse... using gravity?  set the target to the projectiles original position, then in update set the object to look at the target, then you can add forward velocity. with gravity you will get a nice arc, without it will fly forever. i think i have acript for this, but unfortunately, it has colliders. how are you detecting a hit without colliders? just curious.

Comment: @PrinceOfRavens well...I am using colliders to activate the method, but I am not using them to detect the direction. This is a golf shooter so it's essentially a 2d action in a 3d world since I only use the x and z values for velocity. what I'm struggling is that I can't get my direction to rotate relatively to the camera position at all times. I'm gonna add a picture so you can see what I'm saying.

Comment: Could it be the use of mouse Delta? Your x is inverted, try negative x

Answer (score 2):

## `OnMouseUp` is fundamentally a collider method.

Meaning, the mouse MUST be over the GameObject's collider for the GameObject this code is attached to. If you want to move away from using colliders, then you need to move away from this method.

The generic works-anywhere way of saying "is the mouse button up or down?" is the static methods available in the `Input` class:

- `Input.GetMouseButtonDown()` True on the single frame after the mouse button is depressed
- `Input.GetMouseButtonUp()` True on the single frame after the mouse button is released
- `Input.GetMouseButton()` True any frame the mouse button is depressed (otherwise false)

Comment: I'm using OnMouseDown/Up just to ensure the initial click is on the game object I'm trying to move. I don't want to activate the shooting if the player clicks on a random point on the screen.

Comment: You can accomplish that another way as well. Using a raycast (that's how OnMouseDown works anyway).

Answer (score 0):

So I think I have a solution finally and I thought I'd share it for people who might be interested.

The challenge was to rotate mouse delta's direction according to camera position so it gives a natural vibe to the player when dragging and releasing the ball for putting. I did some tests to see where my code had problems rotating delta direction properly(so it matches the screen) and realized when I'm "looking from" (0,0,1) for comparison while the camera's x position is positive it works fine. But when x is negative it doesn't **because** `Vector3.Angle` doesn't return a negative value *as far as I'm concerned* so I just multiplied the result with minus. Seems to work.

Here is the final code:

```
    private void Start()
{
    rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

void OnMouseDown()
{
    ballPos = Input.mousePosition;
}

void OnMouseUp()
{
    Vector2 m_direction = Input.mousePosition - ballPos;
    Vector3 direction = new Vector3(m_direction.x, 0, m_direction.y);
    float userDrag = Mathf.Clamp(direction.magnitude, 0f, maxVelocity);
    direction = Translation(direction);
    direction = Vector3.Normalize(direction);
    rigidbody.velocity = (direction * userDrag) * force;
}

private Vector3 Translation(Vector3 direction)
{
    float angle = GetAngle();
    Quaternion translatedAngle = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.up);
    direction = translatedAngle * direction;
    return direction;
}

private float GetAngle()
{
    Vector3 camPos = Camera.main.transform.position;
    camPos.y = 0;
    if (camPos.x > 0)
    {
        angle = Vector3.Angle(Vector3.forward, camPos);
    }
    else if (camPos.x <0)
    { angle = -Vector3.Angle(Vector3.forward, camPos); }
    return angle;
}
```

please do share if you have suggestions regarding the code.